# Trying to run from VSCode instead of the Terminal since Pressing a button is way easier then going into to the terminal

Tags: python-3.x, directory, interpreter

I just got a new Macbook Pro and I wanted to see running code from VScode works.  So I created a simple hello world in python and I keep getting an errror.  I have anaconda downloaded and I am using the base conda Interpreter. [Shows the kind of error I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZF6Z7.png).

'''
/Users/joshuadeville/anaconda3/bin/python "/Users/joshuadeville/DevFold
er/print("hello world").py"
/Users/joshuadeville/anaconda3/bin/python: can't open file '/Users/joshuadeville/DevFolder/print(hello': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
'''

This is the error I keep getting but say if ran the code through the terninal python3 helloworld.py, it would work.  I just wnat to press the run button in the top hand corner

I tried using different interpeters that VScode provided but it did not work.  For example if I were to use the python 3.9.6 64-bit interpreter it would give me a different error messssage.  Mostly the same but a little different.

```
 /usr/bin/python3 "/Users/joshuadeville/DevFolder/print("hello world").py"
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3: can't open file '/Users/joshuadeville/DevFolder/print(hello': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

**/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3** is the part thats different and I dont understand why.  **The goal is to get the programming running from pushing the button in the top right corner**.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. **another thing I am new to programming**

[Error message of the trying a different interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVQcz.png)

Comment: most likely running it from the wrong folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly rename your file from `print("hello world").py` to `print_hello_world.py` and then try to execute again.
It does not accept **inverted commas( "" )** in the filename, thus getting error.